# Django rest framework Database thread pool management

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

How does django rest framework internally manage Database connection pool. Does it persist a DB connection or it is one DB connection for each DB call? Can we configure Database thread pool connection in Django ?

Answer (score 3):

The Django REST framework simply uses Django's features regarding the db connectivity.

> Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the maximum age defined by `CONN_MAX_AGE` or when it isn’t usable any longer.

You can find much detail on the persistency of DB connections, which is a topic too broad to cover in here, on the [relevant Django docs article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/#connection-management).